# Using EXPLAIN in a query, where should I start looking for optimization?

Tags: postgresql

I've got a query that takes 3 hours in postgres using 512MB of work_mem.

The query:

```
            SELECT
                nextval(
                    'rpro_vistas_hd.seq_ventas_inventario_cod'
                ) AS COD,
                MAX (tmpsem.fecha) AS fecha_inventario,
                MAX (inve.inventario_monto) AS MONTO_INVENTARIO,
                MAX (inve.inventario_unidades) AS "UNIDADES_INVENTARIO",
                CASE
            WHEN SUM (venta.monto_venta) IS NULL THEN
                0
            ELSE
                CAST (
                    SUM (venta.monto_venta) AS BIGINT
                )
            END AS "MONTO_VENTA",
             CASE
            WHEN SUM (venta.unidad_venta) IS NULL THEN
                0
            ELSE
                CAST (
                    SUM (venta.unidad_venta) AS BIGINT
                )
            END AS "UNIDADES_VENTA",
             ll.cod_local AS "COD_LOCAL",
             prod.cod_plu AS "COD_PLU_PRODUCTO",
             prod.cod_plu_retail AS "COD_PLU_RETAIL",
             9999 :: NUMERIC AS "COD_PERIODO",
             to_char(- 1, '99') AS historial_alerta,
             CASE
            WHEN SUM (venta.unidad_venta / 7) > 0 THEN
                CASE
            WHEN (
                MAX (inve.inventario_unidades) / SUM (venta.unidad_venta / 7)
            ) IS NULL THEN
                0
            ELSE
                CAST (
                    MAX (inve.inventario_unidades) / SUM (venta.unidad_venta / 7) AS INTEGER
                )
            END
            ELSE
                0
            END AS rotacion_inventario,
             CASE
            WHEN (SUM(venta.unidad_venta) > 0) THEN
                (
                    SUM (venta.monto_venta) / SUM (venta.unidad_venta)
                ) * 1.19
            ELSE
                ((- 999999)) :: INTEGER
            END AS precio_promedio,
             bool_or(habi.habilitado_retailer) AS "HABILITADO_LOCAL",
             SUM (
                res.monto_ventas_ultimo_anio_movil
            ) AS "MONTO_VENTAS_ULTIMO_ANIO_MOVIL",
             CASE
            WHEN MAX (opp.oportunidad_mo) IS NULL THEN
                0
            ELSE
                MAX (opp.oportunidad_mo)
            END AS oportunidad_monto,
             CASE
            WHEN MAX (opp.oportunidad_un) IS NULL THEN
                0
            ELSE
                MAX (opp.oportunidad_un)
            END AS oportunidad_inventario
            FROM
                rpro_vistas_hd.perfil_1_clr_ultimo_inventario inve
            INNER JOIN rpro_dim.dim_locales ll ON inve.cod_local = ll.cod_local
            INNER JOIN rpro_dim.dim_productos_retail prod ON prod.cod_plu_retail = inve.cod_plu_retail
            AND inve.cod_plu = prod.cod_plu
            AND ll.cod_retailer = prod.cod_retailer
            AND ll.cod_cadena = prod.cod_cadena
            JOIN rpro_vistas_hd.perfil_1_clr_periodo_diario_y_semanal AS tmpsem ON tmpsem.fecha = inve.fecha_inventario
            AND ll.cod_cadena = tmpsem.cod_cadena
            LEFT JOIN rpro_vistas_hd.perfil_1_clr_ultima_oportunidad opp ON opp.cod_local = inve.cod_local
            AND opp.cod_plu = inve.cod_plu
            AND opp.cod_plu_retail = inve.cod_plu_retail
            LEFT JOIN rpro_admin.rms_habilitacion AS habi ON habi.cod_plu_retail = prod.cod_plu_retail
            AND habi.cod_plu = prod.cod_plu
            AND habi.cod_local = ll.cod_local
            LEFT JOIN rpro_vistas_hd.perfil_1_clr_resumen_producto_por_local_full AS res ON res.cod_local = ll.cod_local
            AND res.cod_plu_retail = prod.cod_plu_retail
            AND res.cod_plu_producto = prod.cod_plu
            LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT
                    vvdd.id_dim_local,
                    vvdd.id_dim_prod_retail,
                    SUM (
                        vvdd.sellout_dia_actual_mon
                    ) AS monto_venta,
                    SUM (
                        vvdd.sellout_dia_actual_uni
                    ) AS unidad_venta
                FROM
                    rpro_dim.dim_ventas_diarias AS vvdd
                JOIN rpro_dim.dim_tiempo_diario AS tmp ON tmp.id_dim_tiempo_diario = vvdd.id_dim_tiempo_diario
                JOIN rpro_dim.dim_locales ll ON vvdd.id_dim_local = ll.id_dim_local
                JOIN rpro_dim.dim_productos_retail pp ON vvdd.id_dim_prod_retail = pp.id_dim_prod_retail
                RIGHT JOIN rpro_vistas_hd.perfil_1_clr_periodo_diario_y_semanal tmpsem ON vvdd.id_dim_tiempo_diario = tmpsem.id_dim_tiempo_diario
                AND ll.cod_cadena = tmpsem.cod_cadena
                GROUP BY
                    vvdd.id_dim_local,
                    vvdd.id_dim_prod_retail
            ) AS venta ON venta.id_dim_local = ll.id_dim_local
            AND venta.id_dim_prod_retail = prod.id_dim_prod_retail
            AND prod.cod_plu != 'NOCORRESPONDE'
            GROUP BY
                prod.cod_plu,
                ll.cod_local,
                prod.cod_plu_retail
            ORDER BY
                ll.cod_local,
                prod.cod_plu_retail;
```

When I execute EXPLAIN on this query I've got this:

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=694653.37..706072.47 rows=1 width=1515)
Group Key: ll.cod_local, prod.cod_plu_retail, prod.cod_plu
->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=694653.37..706072.34 rows=1 width=1451)
    Join Filter: ((res.cod_local)::text = (ll.cod_local)::text)
    ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=694652.95..706038.43 rows=1 width=1447)
          Join Filter: (((opp.cod_local)::text = (inve.cod_local)::text) AND ((opp.cod_plu)::text = (inve.cod_plu)::text) AND ((opp.cod_plu_retail)::text = (inve.cod_plu_retail)::text))
          ->  Merge Join  (cost=694652.95..696760.40 rows=1 width=2633)
                Merge Cond: (((ll.cod_local)::text = (inve.cod_local)::text) AND ((prod.cod_plu_retail)::text = (inve.cod_plu_retail)::text) AND ((prod.cod_plu)::text = (inve.cod_plu)::text))
                Join Filter: (tmpsem.cod_cadena = ll.cod_cadena)
                ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=662750.31..662799.00 rows=4808 width=1323)
                      Merge Cond: (((ll.cod_local)::text = (habi.cod_local)::text) AND ((prod.cod_plu_retail)::text = (habi.cod_plu_retail)::text) AND ((prod.cod_plu)::text = (habi.cod_plu)::text))
                      ->  Sort  (cost=662737.93..662749.95 rows=4808 width=1322)
                            Sort Key: ll.cod_local, prod.cod_plu_retail, prod.cod_plu
                            ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=661432.51..662443.90 rows=4808 width=1322)
                                  Hash Cond: ((vvdd.id_dim_local = ll.id_dim_local) AND (vvdd.id_dim_prod_retail = prod.id_dim_prod_retail))
                                  Join Filter: ((prod.cod_plu)::text <> 'NOCORRESPONDE'::text)
                                  ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=652944.88..653562.94 rows=22475 width=72)
                                        Group Key: vvdd.id_dim_local, vvdd.id_dim_prod_retail
                                        ->  Sort  (cost=652944.88..653001.07 rows=22475 width=48)
                                              Sort Key: vvdd.id_dim_local, vvdd.id_dim_prod_retail
                                              ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1307.72..651320.38 rows=22475 width=48)
                                                    ->  Seq Scan on perfil_1_clr_periodo_diario_y_semanal tmpsem_1  (cost=0.00..1.84 rows=84 width=8)
                                                    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1307.72..7751.11 rows=268 width=56)
                                                          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1307.43..7665.71 rows=268 width=56)
                                                                ->  Hash Join  (cost=1307.15..7583.30 rows=268 width=56)
                                                                      Hash Cond: (vvdd.id_dim_local = ll_1.id_dim_local)
                                                                      Join Filter: (ll_1.cod_cadena = tmpsem_1.cod_cadena)
                                                                      ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on dim_ventas_diarias vvdd  (cost=900.95..6307.55 rows=53511 width=52)
                                                                            Recheck Cond: (id_dim_tiempo_diario = tmpsem_1.id_dim_tiempo_diario)
                                                                            ->  Bitmap Index Scan on dim_ventas_diarias_id_dim_tiempo_diario_idx  (cost=0.00..887.58 rows=53511 width=0)
                                                                                  Index Cond: (id_dim_tiempo_diario = tmpsem_1.id_dim_tiempo_diario)
                                                                      ->  Hash  (cost=358.31..358.31 rows=3831 width=8)
                                                                            ->  Seq Scan on dim_locales ll_1  (cost=0.00..358.31 rows=3831 width=8)
                                                                ->  Index Only Scan using dim_tiempo_diario_pkey on dim_tiempo_diario tmp  (cost=0.28..0.30 rows=1 width=4)
                                                                      Index Cond: (id_dim_tiempo_diario = vvdd.id_dim_tiempo_diario)
                                                          ->  Index Only Scan using id_dim_prod_retail_hist_pkey2 on dim_productos_retail pp  (cost=0.29..0.31 rows=1 width=4)
                                                                Index Cond: (id_dim_prod_retail = vvdd.id_dim_prod_retail)
                                  ->  Hash  (cost=8415.51..8415.51 rows=4808 width=1266)
                                        ->  Merge Join  (cost=7962.17..8415.51 rows=4808 width=1266)
                                              Merge Cond: ((ll.cod_cadena = prod.cod_cadena) AND (ll.cod_retailer = prod.cod_retailer))
                                              ->  Sort  (cost=586.32..595.90 rows=3831 width=230)
                                                    Sort Key: ll.cod_cadena, ll.cod_retailer
                                                    ->  Seq Scan on dim_locales ll  (cost=0.00..358.31 rows=3831 width=230)
                                              ->  Sort  (cost=7375.85..7501.36 rows=50204 width=1044)
                                                    Sort Key: prod.cod_cadena, prod.cod_retailer
                                                    ->  Seq Scan on dim_productos_retail prod  (cost=0.00..3456.04 rows=50204 width=1044)
                      ->  Sort  (cost=12.37..12.52 rows=60 width=1251)
                            Sort Key: habi.cod_local, habi.cod_plu_retail, habi.cod_plu
                            ->  Seq Scan on rms_habilitacion habi  (cost=0.00..10.60 rows=60 width=1251)
                ->  Sort  (cost=31902.64..32407.94 rows=202119 width=1322)
                      Sort Key: inve.cod_local, inve.cod_plu_retail, inve.cod_plu
                      ->  Hash Join  (cost=2.89..14091.06 rows=202119 width=1322)
                            Hash Cond: (inve.fecha_inventario = tmpsem.fecha)
                            ->  Seq Scan on perfil_1_clr_ultimo_inventario inve  (cost=0.00..10262.35 rows=481235 width=1318)
                            ->  Hash  (cost=1.84..1.84 rows=84 width=8)
                                  ->  Seq Scan on perfil_1_clr_periodo_diario_y_semanal tmpsem  (cost=0.00..1.84 rows=84 width=8)
          ->  Seq Scan on perfil_1_clr_ultima_oportunidad opp  (cost=0.00..4880.10 rows=251310 width=1612)
    ->  Index Scan using perfil_1_clr_resumen_producto_por_local_fu_cod_plu_producto_idx on perfil_1_clr_resumen_producto_por_local_full res  (cost=0.42..33.82 rows=8 width=1254)
          Index Cond: ((cod_plu_producto)::text = (prod.cod_plu)::text)
          Filter: ((cod_plu_retail)::text = (prod.cod_plu_retail)::text)
```

Given this query plan, where should I start doing optimizations? I was thinking on adding indexes to this:

```
(((opp.cod_local)::text = (inve.cod_local)::text) AND ((opp.cod_plu)::text = (inve.cod_plu)::text) AND ((opp.cod_plu_retail)::text = (inve.cod_plu_retail)::text))
```

Any hint is really appreciated. Lots of this tables do not have indexes, that's why I need to know if using EXPLAIN and applying indexes to the columns using different comparators is a good place to start. Or maybe the effort should go in optimizing the query?

Comment: Let's see the schema, including indexes, and the query. Also prune the query down to the smallest query that is still very slow.

Comment: Let's assume there are no indexes. The question is where to look on the query planner and the query itself to find improvements. Is it neccesarry the schemas? I added the query, tomorrow I can add the table structures.

Comment: it is necessary to know the indexes, because if they aren't being used it can be because of the way the query id written, for example an implicit cast or datatype mismatch that causes the optimizer to bypass the index. Such things are often subtle and without the details it's impossible to know. Sometimes it's hard to know *with* the details.

Comment: For this execution plan the only thing I can think of that could be improved with an index is the `Seq Scan on perfil_1_clr_ultima_oportunidad`, but if that's *really* only executed once, it would not make much difference. Here we come to the core of the problem: we don't know if the estimates are correct or not. Run the query with `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` and show that execution plan. Then it will be possible to say more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your subquery (aliased as `venta`) refers to the table `rpro_vistas_hd`, which means it is a [*correlated subquery*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery), which in turn means **it is executed for every row of the preceding joins**.

To compound the problem, you are right joining to the outer table, and right joins perform badly anyway.

Rewrite your query to not use a correlated subquery.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked tremendously great. We are testing the results but it seems ok for now. Will post the fixed query with your suggestion.